# Пропал перевод в разделе "Влияние" на странице участника

Tags: дефект, локализация

Наблюдается как на основной версии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так и на мете

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикладывать скрин не буду, но в мобильной версии сайта тоже.

Comment: переводы опубликованы

Comment: @МихаилРебров договорились ставить тревогу на вопросе с указанием модератору поставить метку [meta-tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ речь про тревогу после публикации переводов или же наоборот подтверждения в  traducir (насколько я понимаю, модераторы также могут подтверждать)?

Comment: @МихаилРебров лучше ставить, когда уже можно проверить работоспособность вживую на сайте.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо. Я в ближайшее время еще какое-то количество переводов накатаю и отмечу их той же меткой.

Answer (score 2):

#### helpful flags

Нашёл целых 3 токена `helpful flags`

Добавил перевод:

- полезных тревог (*несколько*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18062
- полезных тревог (*много*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18063
- полезная тревога (*одна*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18064

#### people reached

Также нашел 3 непереведенных токена в для разных числительных

Добавил перевод:

- затронуто (*несколько*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18363
- затронуто (*много*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18364
- затронут (*один*)
  https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18365

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.

---

**Опубликовано:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]